Why $d\mu (q)\delta (k,q)$ is $G$-invariant?
Let $G$ be a Lie group acting transitively on  a smooth manifold $M$ endowed with a quasi-invariant measure $\mu$ (then there exists Radon-Nikodym derivative $\rho_f$ for every $f\in G$). For $k\in M$, we introduce a "Dirac delta function" $\delta (k,\cdot )$ such that $$\int_{M}d\mu (q)\delta (k,q)\phi (q)\equiv \phi (k)$$ for any text function $\phi$ on $M$. The definition of the delta function $\delta$ relies on the meausre $\mu$. Let us denote by $\delta_{\mu}$ the delta function associated with $\mu$. If $\rho$ is some positive function on $M$ and $d\nu (q)=\rho (q)d\mu (q)$ is a new measure, then the delta function $\delta_{\nu}$ associated with $\nu$ differes from $\delta_{\mu}$ by a factor $\rho$: $$\delta_{\nu}(k,q)=\frac{\delta_{\mu}(k,q)}{\rho (q)}$$. My question is that why  $d\mu (q)\delta (k,q)$ is $G$-invariant? In other words, why for any $f\in G$, we have $$\delta_{\mu}(f\cdot k,f\cdot q)=\frac{\delta_{\mu}(k,q)}{\rho_f (q)}?$$
In fact, if the above identity holds, then we have $$d\mu (f\cdot q)\delta (f\cdot k,f\cdot q)=d\mu (q)\rho_f (q)\frac{\delta_{\mu}(k,q)}{\rho_f (q)}=d\mu (q)\delta_{\mu}(k,q).$$
